# Epsilon N proof with $n$-th powers for a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Let's say this is part of an epsilon N proof : $|3^{n+1} - 5\cdot 2^{n-5}|<\epsilon$.

If we have $n$-th powers in equation how do we generally go about ending the proof?
This inequality is part of the proof for :
$$e_n = \frac{4\cdot3^{n+1} + 2\cdot4^n}{5\cdot2^n+4^{n+2}}$$

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4\cdot3^{n+1} + 2\cdot4^n}{5\cdot2^n+4^{n+2}} &=
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n+1}} + \frac{2}{4^2}}{5\cdot\frac{2^n}{4^{n+2}}+1}\\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}e_n  = \frac{1}{8}
\end{align}$$

If we set $$\left|\frac{4\cdot3^{n+1} + 2\cdot4^n}{5\cdot2^n+4^{n+2}} - \frac{1}{8}  \right|<\epsilon$$
After some transformations we arrive with
$|3^{n+1} - 5\cdot2^{n-5}|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Since $3^{n+1}$ and $5\times2^{n-5}$ are both integers, and not equal to each other, $|3^{n+1}-5\times2^{n-5}|$ is at least one, so you won't have much luck proving it's less than epsilon.

Comment: Nice remark. But what other way can it be done?Answer with explanation would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not divide by
$4^n+$ other terms.
That makes it easier.